# Random picking of operators (add,sub) with conditions

Tags: python, math, pycharm, logic

```
import operator
import random
# these modules will help with the random picking of operators

ops = {"+": operator.add, "-": operator.sub}
a = ["+", "-"]  #this is to do the random.choice() function
b = float(ops[random.choice(a)](0, 1))  #these can only take 2 parameters, don't ask me why 
c = float(ops[random.choice(a)](2, 3))
d = float(ops[random.choice(a)](4, 5))
e = float(ops[random.choice(a)](6, 7))
f = float(ops[random.choice(a)](8, 9))
print(b+c+d+e+f)  #I have no idea how to do random operators here so i just added

while b+c+d+e+f != 5: #to over and over until i get 5
    if b+c+d+e+f == 5: #if that finally happens...
        print(b+c+d+e+f) #print 5
```

So the idea is to use random operators between numbers 0-9 to get 5.
I literally don't know what code to use. The `operator.add()` function only take 2 parameters.
if anybody can give me an idea how to enter more parameters, That would really help.
To put it simply, the numbers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 need to have + or minus go between each number, to get the number 5.

Comment: So do you need 5 random numbers and 4 random operators?

Comment: FYI, `ops = [add, sub]; random.choice(ops)` would do just fine instead of the double-indirect way you're doing it…

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most efficient or elegant method, but it will do the trick. Always put your while loop around what needs to be done. In your example, only b+c+d+e+f is only calculated over and over again while the operators and values for b, c, d, e and f do not change.

```
import random

result = 0
result_str = ""
while result != 5:
    result = 0
    result_str = ""
    for i in range(0,10):
#         here is random decision between operators
        if bool(random.getrandbits(1)):
            result += i
            result_str = result_str + "+" + str(i)
        else:
            result -= i
            result_str = result_str + "-" + str(i)
print(result_str)
```

Comment: One more thing, i realised it only gives the equation, is there a way to make sure it  gives the answer as well? It's not much of a problem though.

Comment: As in, that it gives '5' as well? just `print(result)` at the bottom will do. Also, could you upvote the answer if it's correct?